# JSON HTML table using jquery

Tags: jquery, json

Here is my json that I produce, but how can I get it into an html table?

```
[
    {
        "basicColor":"blue",
        "manufacturer": {
            "name":"lavalamp.com"
        },
        "costBook": {
            "unitPrice":10.99
        },
        "price":10.99
    },
    {
        "basicColor":"red",
        "manufacturer": {
            "name":"volcaniclava.net"
        },
        "costBook": {
            "unitPrice":15.99
        },
        "price":15.99
    },
    {
        "basicColor":"purple",
        "manufacturer": {},
        "costBook": { "unitPrice":12.99 },
        "price":12.99
    },
    {
        "basicColor":"yellow",
        "manufacturer": {},
        "costBook":{"unitPrice":9.99},
        "price":9.99
    }
]
```

I have tried

```
  $.getJSON('/home/jlpourt1/workspace/LavaLamp/lava.json', function(data) {
{
    var tr;
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    tr = $('<tr/>');
    tr.append("<td>" + data[i].LavaLamp + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td>" + data[i].Price + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td>" + data[i].Color + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td>" + data[i].CostBook + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td>" + data[i].Manufacturer + "</td>");
    $('table').append(tr);
    }
    };
    }
```

but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: where did you get the property name `LavaLamp` from?

Comment: your code has quite a few errors

Answer (score 1):

```
var tr = "";
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  tr += "<tr>";
  tr += "<td>" + data[i].manufacturer.name + "</td>";
  tr += "<td>" + data[i].price + "</td>";
  tr += "<td>" + data[i].basicColor + "</td>";
  tr += "<td>" + data[i].costBook.unitPrice + "</td>";
  tr += "</tr>";
}

$('table').append(tr);
```

Look, if your object property is called `costBook` you cannot name it `cost_book` or `costbook` etc, ... hope you got the idea...

If you like you can also do it this way, escaping the *newline* with `\`:

```
var tr="", d=data;
for (var i=0; i<d.length; i++) {      
   tr += "<tr><td>"+ d[i].manufacturer.name  +"</td> \
              <td>"+ d[i].price              +"</td> \
              <td>"+ d[i].basicColor         +"</td> \
              <td>"+ d[i].costBook.unitPrice +"</td></tr>";
}
$('table').append(tr);
```

Comment: No i really don't see you concern. At my worst job (worst as in most behind technology) for Ft. Rucker, we used jQuery everyday, as it was prefered since they could easily bring in fresh eyes and everyone could read it. You wanna talk large data pulls? Try pulling JSON on a company of soldiers. 1 Company would make more than 10K  lines of JSON ... compacted! Still never took longer than a second or 2 to build the table. On top of not using vanilla, i was stuck using ASP inside Sharepoint, which just makes things even slower ... still never had a speed issue or complaint.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience! I agree that for a good workflow in a company where non-JS people need to read/review your jQ -> *jQ-only* is a considerable solution (that might save $ on debugging-time), but, having today JS as the most popular language in the world, I'll never let anyone with jQ-only knowledge review anyone's code. jQ is good to save you **working** time, but when it comes to sensitive parts... I repeat a mix of the both will not only save you money but make a damn good product.

Comment: Well that's nice of you, but I'm not a `jQ-Only` person. In fact, non of my personal apps have anything but JS just because I wanted to keep em short and simple. I was using JS back when it was still a *Netscape* thing. And of course, I was a netscrape kid. After all, they had MS beat by a mile. I'm well aware of the capabilities of JS, but when you're using a lib as your coding language, you should stick with it unless you "have" to deviate, otherwise you compromise the integrity of your work.

Comment: And I love jQuery because, let's face it, it's the BEST JS LIB on the planet. And with today's standards in technology, it's more than well equipped in it's mini-state to handle any job, including apps. I'm sure when i make an app for public use, i'll use jQuery in it rather than vanilla

Answer (score 0):

Looks like most of your values in the main object are objects themselves and are thus the values are not being accessed correctly. Example for manufacturer, you need to access the value as such:

```
tr.append("<td>" + data[i].manufacturer.name + "</td>");
```

Also there doesn't seem to be a value in your object for the value "LavaLamp"?

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot that can be made *better* about your code, however I can show you the more *jQuery* way to rewrite and show some possible errors.

Possible Problems:

```
$.getJSON('/home/jlpourt1/workspace/LavaLamp/lava.json', function(data) {
{ <- EXTRA BRACKET
    var tr;
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    tr = $('<tr/>');
    THERE IS REALLY NO NEED TO REWRITE APPEND EVERYTIME
    YOU CAN INSTEAD USE JQUERY CHAINING |OR|
    SIMPLY USE A COMMA BETWEEN EACH ELEMENT TO APPEND

    tr.append("<td>" + data[i].LavaLamp + "</td>"); <-- WHERE IS THIS PROPERTY COMING FROM?

    tr.append("<td>" + data[i].Price + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td>" + data[i].Color + "</td>");

    THE FOLLOWING ARE OBJECTS AND CANT BE USED AS TEXT
    tr.append("<td>" + data[i].CostBook + "</td>"); 
    tr.append("<td>" + data[i].Manufacturer + "</td>");
    $('table').append(tr);
    }
    };<-- MISSING CLOSING ')' FOR 'getJSON()'
    }
```

### Working Solution

```
$.getJSON('/home/jlpourt1/workspace/LavaLamp/lava.json', function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(i) {
        $('<tr />').append(
            $('<td />', { text: data[i].LavaLamp }),
            $('<td />', { text: data[i].price }),
            $('<td />', { text: data[i].basicColor }),
            $('<td />', { text: data[i].costBook.unitPrice }),
            $('<td />', { text: data[i].manufacturer.name })
        ).appendTo($('table'));
    });
});
```

## jsFiddle

---

If you want to take it a step further, I would suggest a short function for setting text in case the value is not found. Something like:

```
/* setText('String value', 'Alternate String value in case first one is empty'); */
function setText(a,b){return a?a:"string"==typeof b?b:"N/A"};

$.getJSON('/home/jlpourt1/workspace/LavaLamp/lava.json', function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(i) {
        $('<tr />').append(
            $('<td />', { text: setText(data[i].LavaLamp) }),
            $('<td />', { text: setText(data[i].price) }),
...
            $('<td />', { text: setText(data[i].manufacturer.name, 'Manufacturer Not Found') })
...
```

## jsFiddle

---

See Also:

- [jQuery.each()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)
- [jQuery.append()](https://api.jquery.com/append/)
- [jQuery.append()](https://api.jquery.com/appendTo/)
- [jQuery Chaining](http://tobiasahlin.com/blog/quick-guide-chaining-in-jquery/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() 
{
    // ... 

    $.getJSON('/home/jlpourt1/workspace/LavaLamp/lava.json', function(json) 
    {
        $.each(json, function(i, x) 
        {
            var $tr = $('<tr/>').appendTo('table');

            $tr.append('<td>' + x.basicColor + '</td>');
            $tr.append('<td>' + x.manufacturer['name'] + '</td>');
            $tr.append('<td>' + x.costBook['unitPrice'] + '</td>');
            $tr.append('<td>' + x.price + '</td>');
        });
    });   
});
```

Answer (score -2):

There doesn't seem to be an opening tr

```
$.getJSON('/home/jlpourt1/workspace/LavaLamp/lava.json', function(data) {
    var tr;
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        tr = $('<tr>');
        tr.append("<td>" + data[i].LavaLamp + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + data[i].Price + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + data[i].Color + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + data[i].CostBook + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + data[i].Manufacturer + "</td>");
        tr.append("</tr>");
        $('table').append(tr);
    }
 });
```

Comment: This should really be a comment. `tr = $('<tr/>')` creates the `tr` element which contains both tags.

Comment: In that case, you wouldn't append.